# Update tabelas com os mesmos dados na linha

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Quando adiciono uma categoria `A`, e adiciono um produto `X` com a categoria `A` (tabela categorias), após isso se for editar o nome da categoria `A` para categoria `B`, a categoria do produto `X` (tabela produtos) mantém-se com a categoria `A`.

O meu update query é

```
UPDATE Categorias set Categoria = @Categoria WHERE IDCatg = @IDCatg
```

Basicamente queria que, quando a categoria `A` fosse editada (tabela categorias), verificar se há algum produto com a categoria `A` (tabela produtos), e para além de fazer o update à categoria `A` para a `B`, editar a categoria do produto `X` para `B`. Caso a categoria não esteja em nenhum produto, editar normalmente, para esse efeito a query acima descrita.

Comment: Na sua tabela produtos você guarda o texto da Categoria ou IDCatg? O correto seria o ID dessa forma você automaticamente vai ter os produtos sempre atualizados.

Comment: Mostre como está a estrutura da sua tabela `Produtos`

Comment: Guardo a Categoria.

A estrutura é: IDProduto, Marca, Nome, Categoria.

Comment: Não pode mudar a estrutura pra salvar o ID? Isso vai te evitar muita dor de cabeça

Comment: Nesta fase não tenho como.

Há alguma solução para ele editar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe dois problemas graves na sua estrutura por não salvar o `IDCatg` na tabela `Produtos`.

1. Quando sua Categoria tiver alteração na descrição ela vai ficar desatualizada na tabela `Produtos`. (Sua situação atual)
2. Quando você for atualizar a descrição da categoria na tabela `Produtos` você não sabe se aquela descrição pertence ao `IDCatg` que você quer alterar. Então pode acontecer de você atualizar a Categoria de IDCatg diferentes.

-

Se você quer continuar mesmo assim:

```
UPDATE Produtos, Categorias
SET Produtos.Categoria = @Categoria,
    Categorias.Categoria = @Categoria
WHERE Produtos.Categoria = Produtos.Categoria
  AND Categorias.IDCatg = @IDCatg
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Não haverá problema porque a categoria nos produtos não é editada colocando à mão, mas sim por dropdownlist que consulta a tabela Categorias.

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal Tudo bem, então se resolveu seu problema por favor marque como a solução. :)

Comment: Está a dar um erro de syntax entre o Produtos p e o SET.

Comment: Remove o alias `p` e os `p. `, continua dando erro?

Comment: Desta maneira?

UPDATE Produtos SET Categoria = @Categoria 
WHERE Categoria IN 
(SELECT c.Categoria FROM Categorias c WHERE c.IDCatg = @IDCatg)

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal Isso, não funciona?

Comment: Funciona, mas apenas edita a categoria do produto, não edita a categoria da tabela categorias.

Outra situação é se tiver uma categoria que não esteja definida num produto, não é possível editar.

Comment: Como eu falei na resposta é pra executar dois update, você quer fazer tudo em 1 só?

Comment: Exacto, tudo na mesma query.

Algo do género: se a categoria estiver a ser usada em algum produto, ele executa (a query abaixo ainda não está a actualizar a tabela categorias, apenas faz a actualização da linha Categoria dos produtos)

"UPDATE Produtos SET Categoria = .@Categoria WHERE Categoria in (SELECT c.Categoria FROM Categorias c WHERE c.IDCatg = -@IDCatg)"

Caso a Categoria não esteja em uso em algum produto, executa

"UPDATE Categorias set Categoria = @Categoria WHERE IDCatg =-@IDCatg"

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal Atualizei minha resposta com sua necessidade, faça um teste :)

Comment: Agradeço a sua solução. Está a dar incorrect syntax near Produtos, near SET e Produtos.Categoria.

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal Verifica se as tabelas e campos estão corretos na minha resposta

Comment: Está correcto tudo sim.

Comment: Ficou ok, para tal bastou:

 "UPDATE Produtos SET Categoria = .@Categoria WHERE Categoria IN (SELECT c.Categoria FROM Categorias c WHERE c.IDCatg = .@IDCatg)"


 "UPDATE Categorias set Categoria = .@Categoria WHERE IDCatg = .@IDCatg"

Agradeço a ajuda prestada.